# Problems with 'return' in void function with sqlite in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am at the beginning of learning how to use sqlite in c++.
I coded the following function. Now I would like to return the value to my main function, but it does not work and I can't find out why.

When I take out the

```
return value;
```

everything works like charm. And it prints out the number I was looking for, but when I put it in, the compiler tells me:

```
main2.cpp: In Funktion »void query(sqlite3*, const char*, int)«:
main2.cpp:58:12: Fehler: Return-Anweisung mit Wert in »void« zurückgebender Funktion [-fpermissive]
```

which is translated:

```
main2.cpp:58:12: Error: Return-Instruction with value in »void« returned function [-fpermissive]
```

Does anybody have an idea?

```
void query(sqlite3* db, const char* sql, int id)
{
  int rc;

  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
  {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can not prepare: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  exit(0);
  }

  rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, id);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) 
  {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can not bind: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  exit(0);
  }

  rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
  if (rc != SQLITE_ROW && rc != SQLITE_DONE) 
  {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can not step: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  exit(0);
  }

  if (rc == SQLITE_BUSY)
  {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can not step (busy): %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  exit(0);
  }

  if (rc == SQLITE_LOCKED)
  {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can not step (locked): %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  exit(0);
  }

  if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) 
  {
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  printf("not found");
  }

  // save data
  int value = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);

  return value;

  printf("%i\n", value);

  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

Thank you very much!
~ AMK

Comment: Well... that's kind of the definition of `void`...

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander So right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is defined as having a `void` return type... which means you can only return void.

If you need to return a value, you need to change the return type of your function (perhaps to `int`).

And whatever you do, realize that any statements after that `return` where it's currently located will absolutely never be executed.

---

```
main2.cpp:58:12: Error: Return-Instruction with value in »void« returned function [-fpermissive]
```

In even more clearer English (because that's apparently not clear enough):

Your function is designated as `void` returned.  You're trying to return something from it, and that's an error.

What's not to understand?